# Is it possible to server side render only one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a react app which is rendered on the client side. Now I have a component which I want to render on the server side. I am doing this because the component will construct its layout from a json and I do not want to parse the json once on the server and again on the client to render the component.

Right now, I am doing `renderToString(<Component/>)` and sending it to the client. The client then does `ReactDOM.hydrate(component,document.getElementById('someDivId'))`. But it only renders the component as a string. It is not rendering it as an element. The container on which I am trying to render the component is a client-side rendered react app.

Example code as below

*server.js*

```
app.get('/component/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
  const markup =  renderToString(
    <div>Hello</div>
  )
  let jsonModel = {
    markup
  }
  return res.json(jsonModel);
})
```

*client.js*

```
getComponent(id).then(data => {
     ReactDOM.hydrate(data.markup, document.getElementById('someDivId'));
});
```

Is it possible to render only one component on the server side? Or do I have to render the whole app on the server side?

Comment: were you able to implement something like that ? I am in a similar situation

Comment: Unfortunately, Couldn't find a solution for this and just stuck to client side rendering.

Comment: :( yeah I believe I will have to do the same. Thanks for your answer!